# How do you say "Where is Beijing?"

Tags: word-choice, usage, sentence-structure

In Chinese will we say, "Beijing zai nār/nali?". Because I just learned to say, "Lundun zai Ying Guo." Plus, "Where is your home?" is, "Nide jia zai nar?" So using these rules, is it acceptable?

What about, "Beijing shi nar/nali?"

And can we also say "Beijing zai na guo?" (Which country is Beijing in?")

Are these sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: users recommend searching dictionaries or even web as a whole using e.g. "E phrase 中文＂，北京在哪里？is valid, 北京是在哪里？exists esp. with adverbs like 究竟、到底 （after all）北京究竟是在哪里？or  starting with 那么 so, 那么北京是在哪里？ 北京在哪个（什么）国家？ also exists, for including 是 see preceding example

Comment: All of your sentences are ok, except "Beijing zai na guo". Better say "Beijing zai na ge guo jia".

Comment: To be honest, although `Běijīng shì nǎr/nǎlǐ?` grammatically correct, it sounds weird to me. Mostly questions containing `shì` usually collocates with `shénme` or `shéi`.

Answer (score 1):

The examples you gave are all grammatically correct, but they are slightly different in meaning.

> Beijing zai nār/nali?

This sentence is asking where is Beijing, the person who will be answering the question will tell you the location of Beijing. If I were to answer the question, I will tell you Beijing is physically in Hebei province, in the east part of China.

> Beijing zai na guo?

This question is asking which country is Beijing in, and will be answered by justing telling you Beijing is in China.

> Beijing shi nar/nali?

This is a little different with the previous two, it is not only, or, exactly asking the physical location of Beijing, it is asking about Beijing itself. I will answer as the following, Beijing is the captical city of China, its population is 13 millon and it is in the east part of China and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D  (lol last part though)

Comment: Like using shi, I am asking what are things like in Beijing? Situation in beijjng?

Comment: @Isabel By the last question, you are asking about Beijing generally, therefore the answer really depends.